# Pop up Swing window with both option and textfield

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog

Given such codes:

```
Object[] possibilities = {"ham", "spam", "yam"};
String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                frame,
                "Complete the sentence:\n"
                + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
                "Customized Dialog",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                icon,
                possibilities,
                "ham");
```

[image]

You can see that it pop up a window with options. However, can I have an `JTextField` paralleled with that? So I can get the inputs both from the `option` and the `text field`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a round about way, yes...

[image: Breakfast]

```
JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"ham", "spam", "yam"});

fields.add(field);
fields.add(comboBox);

int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, fields, "Breakfast", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
switch (result) {
    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
        // Process the results...
        break;
}
```

People either forget or don't realise that if you pass a `JComponent` to a `JOptionPane` as the `message` parameter, it will be added to the `JOptionPane`, making it really rather flexibile and powerful

Comment: This looks cool. Can you make a little change so that the user can only either type in in the `textfield` or choose the from the `comboBox`? Set the other one unable when one of them has input or is choosen.

Comment: Yes, you could do that

Comment: Okay, what part of your original question asked for that?  No offense, we're not your code monkeys...

Comment: *"Can you make a little change so that the user can only either type in in the textfield or choose the from the `comboBox`?"* Why not just show an **editable** `JComboBox` instead of the pair of components?